# Storing data efficiently in an array

Tags: c, memory

The problem is the following:

I am storing error codes with IDs `(e.g. 23,53,12,64...)` in an array with a predefined length `(e.g. 10)`.

Now I would like to store some additional bytes to these codes 
`(e.g. **23** (data: 102, 340), **53** (data: 10), **12** (data: 46, 23, 64, 12), **64** (data: 1,2,3))`.

The data length is different for almost each error codes.

What is the best way of storing these additional bytes regarding the memory consumption?

My idea is to calculate the maximum memory I need for storing these additional bytes.

If I have 30 error codes and I would like to make it possible to store 10 of them (if they occur), then the maximum memory for storing the additional bytes can be calculated by summing up the number of the additional bytes of those error codes which require the most additional bytes. So when the 10 errors occur, which require the most additional bytes, the array for storing the additional bytes is just enough.

One error code only present once in a time.

When an error occurs, I save the additional bytes into this array and store a "pointer" (which is just an index of this array) to the error code, where the additional bytes start.

But this causes fragmentation if errors occur and I delete errors.

Defragmenting this array would be an overhead for the CPU.

Any ideas? I need to avoid dynamic memory allocating.

Comment: You need to allocate enough memory to handle the worst-case scenario and that's it. Allocating less memory than that "sometimes" doesn't make sense. Either your program can handle the worst-case scenario or it can't.

Comment: The worst case calculation is that one I mentioned in my question. But it comes with down sides, the fragmentation problem. The easiest way would be allocating _(maximum number of errors I would like to store)*(maximum of the additional bytes)_. It means I could store more additional bytes for those errors, which may not require any additional bytes. This would be wasting memory.

Comment: Don't imagine problems, trigger them, then solve them.

Comment: 30 is a very small number. Don't bother with "memory wasting" unless you really have very little memory on your device.

Comment: Thank you for the comments :) Every byte counts in this case. Another solution would be defining an array for those errors, which have more than 4 (or whatever) additional bytes and defining an array for those, which have lass than 4. This way some bytes could be saved.

Comment: @tomi if every byte counts you should mention this in the question.

Comment: Enough bytes for worst case without wasting memory... sounds like a cat byting its own tail. Please, consider that it is common to distinguish average and worst case. If you _must_ be prepared for worst case then doubts about wasting memory are... a bit useless. You may consider an optimal use of bits. 64 distinct error codes can be stored in 6 bits instead of 8. Using [lossless data compression](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lossless_compression) might be more effective but without knowing the exact characteristics of possible data it's impossible to predict the exact/worst compression ratio.

Comment: When you delete an error then move all other errors to the front and adjust the indexes accordingly. That way the free space will always be in one block at the end. Also why even have indexes? Simply go through the errors and sum up the amount of data they have till you get to the one you want. So you only need a bitfield for present errors and an array for data.

Comment: @tomi This problem can only be solved by using common sense. Bytes saved for _what_? For whom? Isn't this a single core embedded system? There is none else using the RAM but your program. What exactly is your program going to do with that memory, when it isn't executing the worst case? And when doing so, why does it then need to use those extra bytes you have been "saving"?

Comment: I get into discussions like this a lot with rookie embedded programmers. The bottom line is always that they never actually know what they are "saving" for. A rainy day or some such. "Those bytes might be good to have" isn't common sense. Good for what?

Comment: @GoswinvonBrederlow Thank you, it is a good idea to keep the empty blocks alway at the end of the array!

Comment: @Lundin You are right, this is just one small module in a single core embedded system and saving memory is mandatory, so we can use cheaper controllers and implement more functionality.

Comment: Don't forget that adding code also costs memory.

Comment: @stark Different kind of memory though on micro controllers, which given the memory constraint seem to be the target.

Comment: I don't know how your data looks like. Are numbers? can be labeled/numbered somehow? Even if you have to store a whole 30*max(data) size matrix, that matrix can be (30 bits)*(max(data) bits) and you just turn them on/off.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have one array to store the error IDs and another array to store the additional bytes for all errors.  (And do you have yet another array to store the pointers to the additional bytes for each error?)  And your concern is with managing the additional_bytes array and the pointers.  Is that right?

Instead of using separate arrays with pointers, store everything in a single array of structs.

First declare a struct that contains all of the information related to an error.

```
typedef struct ErrorInfo
{
    unsigned int error_id;
    uint8_t additional_data[MAX_ADDITIONAL_BYTES_PER_ERROR];
} ErrorInfo;
```

Then allocate a single array to store multiple errors.

```
ErrorInfo errors_array[MAX_NUMBER_OF_ERRORS];
```

Set an error like this:

```
errors_array[0].error_id = 23;
errors_array[0].additional_data[0] = 102;
errors_array[0].additional_data[1] = 340;  <--- Note that 340 will overflow a byte!
```

This should use less memory than your design because you no longer need to record pointers to the additional bytes for each error.  This also removes your defragmentation issue because each error's additional bytes have a reserved place in the struct array and you no longer need to manage their location in a separate addition_bytes array.

If you must store all the additional bytes for all errors in a separate array then just use a fixed (permanent) offset for each error.  The offset to the additional bytes for error number `n` is equal to `(n - 1) * MAX_ADDITIONAL_BYTES_PER_ERROR`.  This will leave some empty bytes in the array between errors but it will remove the need to store pointers and manage fragmentation.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Yes you see the problem right. The approach you described is what I am using right now. But if there is only one error, which requires 10 bytes of external data and the others require 0, then a lot of memory is allocated for nothing using this approach.

Comment: @tomi Your comment contradicts your question.  If it's possible for every error slot (10?) to contain the error ID that requires 10 additional bytes then you have to allocate for the worst case (10 additional * 10 slots).  When the worst case doesn't occur some of those bytes may be unused.  But don't worry about it.  100 bytes is not a lot.  [YAGNI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_aren%27t_gonna_need_it).  If you encounter a memory crunch later in development there will most likely be better opportunities for savings elsewhere.

Comment: Thanks. No, one error code could only occur once and the number of the occurrence is stored in a counter.

Answer (score -1):

For a read only solution without dynamically changing data I would consider using a run length approach. Code, length, data[length], code, length, data[length] etc...

This is slow to access but if you do not have an index then you will have to trawl through the array too to find the code you want.

You could write some a small program that did the encoding on the host, rather than the target, and printed the array as C code to a file. The host would use a wasteful method where the data size was the max that you would encounter.